# Сохранение изображения в mysql. php

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Не могу понять почему не сохраняется изображение, вроде все верно.
Я знаю что можно хранить изображение в папке, а в бд только путь, но мне интересно почему не могу в бд сохранить.

html

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.html">На главную</a>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="registry.php">
    <p>Ваше Имя:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="name" size="40"></p>
    <p>Ваша Фамилию:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="surname" size="40"></p>
    <p>Ваше Отчество:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="midlename" size="40"></p>
    <p>Ваш email:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="email" size="40"></p>
    <p>Ваш телефон:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="phone" size="40"></p>
    <p>Ваш город:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="sity" size="40"></p>
    <p>Ваша страна:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="country" size="40"></p>
    <p>Ваш фотография:</p>
    <input type="file" name="file"  accept=".JPG, .PNG, .JPEG, .PNG">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxx";
$database = "web_4";
$usertable = "user";


$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die('Oops');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$midlename = $_POST['midlename'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$city = $_POST['sity'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$file =  $_POST['file'];




$sql = "INSERT INTO $usertable (name, surname, midlename, email, phone, sity, country, photo) VALUE ('$name','$surname','$midlename','$email','$phone','$city','$country','$file') ";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Новый пользователь добавлен <br>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Таким способом его не добавить. погуглите, прежде чем задавать глупые вопросы

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/44610/

Comment: @Bloom это каким местом относится к вопросу записи бинарного поля в БД ?

Comment: дак вот и дал ссылку почитать, что как заносятся данные вообще

Comment: Хранить бинарно файлы в бд это грешно, нужно хранить в файловой системе, а в базе хранить пути и имена файлов